# Kill activity or process for UI restore

Tags: android, android-activity, process, android-lifecycle

How can I reproduce easily killing an activity or killing the process in the background to test that my data are restoring the UI properly?

Answer (score 0):

When calling `finish()` on an activity, the method `onDestroy()` is executed. This method can do things like:

- Dismiss any dialogs the activity was managing.
- Close any cursors the activity was managing.
- Close any open search dialog.

Comment: My question is how to kill a running activity/process on a device or emulator